# How to return list from webservice

Tags: vb.net, web-services, list

within webservce MyService.
DocumentList Class containing properties id, name -- Class is Serializable

```
Public Function getDocList(args...) as List(Of DocumentList)
'code to add to documentlist
'no issue here...
End Function
```

Within project.

```
Dim thisService as New MyService

Sub Main
Dim docList as New List(of DocumentList)
docList = thisService.getDocList(args...)
End Sub
```

I get error - cannot convert -1 dimensional array to generic list of DocumentList.
If I consume DocumentList within the service, no issues. I can iterate with for each. But, within the project, which calls the service, I cannot consume DocumentList.
I have set the service to pass a string, and this is possible. Only the List(Of DocumentList) is an issue.I think I may need reflection, or a proper understanding of collections. Not sure.
Thank you.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild, maybe it is working with stale code.  docList need not be a NEW list: `Dim docList As List(Of String) = thisService.getDocList(args...)` getDocList is the one that needs to create the New List

Comment: good try, but same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim docList as DocumentList()
```

Cannot return a complex type, had to set my DocumentList as an array in the project calling the webservice. 
http://www.asquestion.com/question/60333227137608045/Problem-returning-a-collection-from-a-web-service